# Is it possible to add jspf files to a jsp page without using jsp:include?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, header, footer, jsp-fragments

What I want to achieve is something similar to a master page in asp.net. I'm following a [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller.html#jspf), but I may have missed something cause I have added my header.jspf and footer.jspf to the WEB-INF/jspf folder and index.jsp is outside of WEB-INF. I have added info in web.xml so that certain jsp-pages should automatically add the header and footer. The problem might be that index.jsp can't access anything inside the WEB-INF folder, but I thought I had solved that in a previous step in the tutorial. When I run the project, all I get is what's left of index.jsp after I remove all the header and footer stuff.

I don't want to use: `<%@include file="header.jspf" %>` and `<..jsp:include...>`.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of the project]

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <description>header and footer settings</description>
            <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

**header.jspf:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Webshop</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Webshop</h1>
```

**footer.jspf:**

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use <%@include file="header.jspf" %> and <..jsp:include...> ??

Comment: Well it's no biggie, I just wanted a way to not have to add the same stuff to every jsp, but two rows to add to each jsp isn't a problem. I just wanted to know if there is a way to add the header and footer via the web.xml file.

Comment: So.. you could use SiteMesh. You can create a template page, used for every page in your project, and only the specific site content is in the actual jsp-sites then.

Comment: Explained on: http://uxt.ucsd.edu/uxtuistack/resources/sitemesh/index.html and http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/22/sitemesh.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: If you change your url pattern to `*.jsp` it should work. I have a similar url pattern to yours (`/WEB-INF/view/*`) working on Jetty, but it fails on Tomcat 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm also doing that tutorial, and when I use Tomcat as the server it won't  include the header and the footer, I have to use the glassfish server, is there any way to make tomcat include the header and the footer?

EDIT:

Replacing the default  tag with this one seems to have solved the problem using tomcat as the server

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, use the *Ask Question* button in the upper-right corner to ask new questions.