# Netbeans E-commerce tutorial with prelude/coda not working on Tomcat

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I'm currently doing this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller.html), but the tutorial uses Glassfish as the server and I'm using Tomcat 7.0.22 as the server. I'm trying to include a header and a footer as .jspf files I only get this:

[image]

When it's supposed to look like this:

[image]

It only renders the page without including the header and the footer, also when I go to the category page (http://localhost:8080/AffableBean/category) it renders the page like this:

[image]

When it's supposed to look like this:

[image]

My webxml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

If I try to use a differente web-app tag like this one:

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    
    /TR/xmlschema-1/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-
    app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
```

Only the index page will get rendered correctly but when I want to go to another page like

> http://localhost:8080/AffableBean/category

I get a 404 error

Is it because I'm using Tomcat instead of Glassfish?

Comment: I'm also running the latest Tomcat, that is version 7.0.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong with your properties of your netbeans project. Everything looks fine to me. You can find an image here:

[image]

Please take the following steps and let me know if it provides a solution:

- Create a new netbeans project
- Copy the map 'view' from your old project directly under the directory 'Web pages'.
- Delete the file 'category.jsp' and replace it with the original file from (solution 2, at the end of the page) http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller.html
- Copy the map css from your old project and paste it directly under the directory 'Web pages'.
- Copy 'header.jspf' and footer.jspf from your old project and paste it to the 'view' map.
- Open your 'header.jspf and change the css include line to: < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/affablebean.css" >
- Open the clean 'web.xml' under 'WEB-INF', click on the 'XML' tab and paste http://pastebin.com/89nz4uLP.

**Alternate solution:**
Example header.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <div id="header"> <span class="something">text here</span>
                <div id="banner">

                    <h1><a># Android</a></h1><br/>
                </div><br/>
    </div>
            <div id="menu">
                    <a href="index.jsp">Welcome</a>
                    <a href="#" class="none">|</a>
                    <a href="Register.do">Register</a>
                    <a href="#" class="none">|</a>
                    <a href="Newsflash.jsp">Newsflash</a>
            </div>
```

Include it where you need it in your webpage (jsp), by using

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

As you see you don't need to re-add all the html in the header.jsp, just the part of the header.

Comment: You are not really answering the question. You're basically telling "Sorry, it works for me with `<jsp:include>`, I don't know the answer for `<include-prelude>` and `<include-coda>`".

Comment: Oviously he mentioned "I'm trying to include a header and a footer as .jspf files I only get this" (First screenshot). If he includes it that way, the header/footer should be rendered correctly since I took my example directly from my 'working depot shelf'. It's better taking the time to give an working alternative then just looking and skipping his question. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I know I can use the <jsp:include> tag, but I'm trying to avoid using those 2 lines by including the prelude coda tags

Comment: @Kim: your effort is much appreciated, but this does definitely not answer the OP's question. You're merely ignoring his concrete question/problem and not explaining why it fails and what the solution is. You'd better have posted a comment on the question wherein you suggest the `<jsp:include>` alternative. If you earn at least 50 reputation, then you can also post comments on other's posts.

Comment: @rkrdo: Did you tryout a .jsp file (delete de html/body etc) in place of a .jspf file? I've had issues with a .jspf file in the past when using it as a header.

Comment: @Kim that didn't work :(, I'll keep trying, so it doesn't have anything to do with me using Tomcat instead of Glassfish, maybe an incompatibility issue with the <include-prelude> tags?

Comment: @rkrdo: Not really. Would it be possible to upload the full project so I can take a peek?

Comment: @kim sure https://github.com/rkrdo/example_netbeans , also if I use Glassfish as the server I have no problems

Comment: @BalusC I've edited my previous post, you were right. Hope I'm on the right 'path' :).

Answer (score 1):

Change your web.xml header to:

```
<web-app version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

See also: [Is it possible to add jspf files to a jsp page without using jsp:include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619480/is-it-possible-to-add-jspf-files-to-a-jsp-page-without-using-jspinclude)

Comment: I already have this as my web.xml header. But, I am getting an unexpected exception - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026495/cannot-find-resource-in-web-app-even-after-giving-correct-path